# additional cross-Stack-Exchange-sites score bonuses?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, association-bonus, score

I was recently pleasantly surprised to receive an extra 100 points to all my Stack Exchange scores after both my Stack Overflow and Wordpress accounts got over the 200 mark. Are there other across site bonuses rewarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Apart from the bonus you get for having an account in more than one SE site, and having a reputation higher than 199 in one of those sites (the bonus you are describing), there aren't any other bonuses you get.
Bounties you gain on your answers are similar to bonuses, if you want to call them so.